# What does it mean for states to be in a multiplet of a symmetry group?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, group-theory

Trying to understand the different realizations of symmetries in QFT I stumbled upon these notes

https://indico.cern.ch/event/106673/contributions/1306809/attachments/20980/30332/Natal_Lectures_Part_III.pdf

And, at page 4, I don't really know what the equation

$$
\mathcal{U}(\alpha)\phi_i\mathcal{U}(\alpha)^{-1}=U_{ij}(\alpha)\phi_j
$$

really means. It says that

> Then the states of the theory fall into multiplets of the symmetry group

but in what way is this realted to the former equation? I cannot explain why the equality, and also what the equation on the left means. What is $\phi_i$ ? Why does it transform like that? Any explanation on this equation would be much appreciated. Also some references on the topic would be great too.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, a multiplet meant a set of closely related spectral lines.

Later, it was used by physicists to refer to an irreducible representation of a symmetry group. In particular, the dimension of the multiplet is the dimension of the representing vector space of the associated representation.